# Sonarlint warning: Remove this "exit()" call or ensure it is really required

Tags: php, sonarlint

[Sonarlint](https://www.sonarlint.org/) (a code quality tool) complains about `exit();` calls in my code. The code is a target (`action=""`) in a form that creates a DB row, then redirects to an overview page. Simplified like this:

```php
// do something
// on success:
header('Location: ' . $location);
exit;
```

[Their explanation of this error](https://rules.sonarsource.com/php/RSPEC-1799?search=exit).

Is there is a "proper" way to redirect in such cases without using the `exit()` call? The redirect can happen very early in the file and running through all the other code following this location seems redundant.

I don't want to just make the warning disappear (I know it's possible to do with `// NOSONAR`.) but rather understand how to proper program this piece of code or if this some kind of overzealous quality control thing.

I understand, that `exit();` calls are not testable - the reason for this warning. On the other side, using, for instance, the Browser tester of [Codeception](https://codeception.com/) I can test properly if a redirect is happening.